# How to compare CSV to Postman JSON Response values?

Tags: postman

How to compare CSV to Postman JSON Response values?
I want to compare CSV values to Postman Response value.

For Ex:

My CSV:

Iteration, City, Ramen

1,"Vancouver",100

2,"San Francisco",84

My End Point:
[a link](https://postman-echo.com/get?city=%7B%7BCity%7D%7D&ramen=%7B%7BRamen%7D%7D)

My Tests:

```
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.args.ramen).to.eql(pm.iterationData.get("Ramen"));
});
```

Note: I get files from below URL. Only tests are mine.
[a link](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1559645/RVu4GVAs)

As of now I'm getting below error:

Your test name | AssertionError: expected '84' to deeply equal 84

Comment: The problem is that it is comparing the string '84' with the integer 84, that's the meaning of the "deeply" here. Maybe you have to use another function to check for equality, that does not check for type equality as well.

Comment: That is passed for first value. But second value come from CSV as '84\r' instead of '84'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the csv integer value to a string and using `to.equal` *instead* of `to.eql` (which is equivalent to `to.deep.equal`):

```
pm.expect(jsonData.args.ramen).to.equal(new String(pm.iterationData.get("Ramen")));
```

Comment: That is passed for first value. But second value come from CSV as '84\r' instead of '84'.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected value for `"Ramen"` from your CSV Datafile is `84` of type **Number**.
But your Service returns the property `"ramen"` with value `"84"`  of type **String**.

*Your test fails for a good reason.*

Of course you can change your testdata by casting. But this isn't a good test, because you are changing your expected test-data during runtime to become tests green.

If the response is ok, an the testdata not: 
You need to store the the "Ramen" Values in your CSV as a String:

```
1,"Vancouver","100"
2,"San Francisco","84"
and so on.
```

If the testdata is ok, an the response not:
You have to fix the wrong Servie behaviour.

Comment: Can anyone help on this? This is similar to this question. But for JSON.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696009/how-to-run-json-test-data-in-postman